# wix - check Excel 2013 version

Tags: windows, excel, wix, windows-installer, installation

I am developing Excel plugin with x86 and x32 version and in my Wix installer I want to raise an error if user tries to install x86 version of plugin on x64 version of Excel 2013 and vice versa. I am doing it like this:

snippet from x86 plugin .wxs file:

```
<!-- Check if Excel x86 is installed -->
    <Property Id="EXCEL2013">
      <ComponentSearch Id="DetectExcel2013" Guid="{C8A65ABE-3270-4FD7-B854-50C8082C8F39}" Type="file"/>
    </Property>
    <Condition Message="Please install Excel 2013x86.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR EXCEL2013]]>
    </Condition>
```

snnipet from x64 plugin .wxs file:

```
<!-- Check if Excel x64 is installed -->
    <Property Id="EXCEL2013">
      <ComponentSearch Id="DetectExcel2013" Guid="{E3BD1151-B9CA-4D45-A77E-51A6E0ED322A}" Type="file"/>
    </Property>
    <Condition Message="Please install Excel 2013x64.">
      <![CDATA[EXCEL2013]]>
    </Condition>
```

I have found this Guids on the https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bdcd8850-0b6a-4fd1-a0cb-647ff12c3088/finding-the-component-id-for-office-2013?forum=vsto and it seems reliable.
But there is problem. This check works like a charm on x86 Excel machine - the C8A65ABE... guid is found there. But that is not the case for the E3BD1151... guid on the x64 Excel  machine. Seems that both version of Excel (x86 and x64) have the same C8A65ABE... guid. How to reliable distinguish Excel 2013 version since both version have the same C8A65ABE... guid?

Comment: In your x64plugin.wxs file do you have the property "Platform="x64" set? Otherwise wix will be looking at the x86 registry location for the the GUID.

Answer (score 1):

If you support both x86 and x64 systems then you need two MSI files.

One will be an x86 MSI and search for x86 Excel (and note that these guids are for the PIAs) and contain only an x86 plugin. This MSI needs a launch condition that prevents it installing on x64 systems because you have a separate MSI for that. Your condition could be something like -not VersionNT64-

The other will be an x64 MSI that will have both x64 and x86 versions of the plugin. This is because Microsoft seems to recommend use of x86 Office on x64 systems, and so most of the time an x64 system will have an x86 Office and an x86 PIA, which is why you are detecting it on x64 systems. I think you're assuming that x64 systems must have x64 Office, which is not the case. x86 apps work fine on x64 systems.

So I suspect that in fact those searches are ok - you say the search doesn't work on an x64 machine, but my guess is that it's got x86 Office on it. You'll need to test on a system that explicitly has x64 Office installed, which I believe is rarer than you think. On an x64 system you'll be activating the x86 or x64 plugin depending on the component search tells you about the bitness of Office, and most of the time it may well be the x86 version.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your point but I think that is not the case. I implemented everything as you said - I also have a check for 2010 Excel which works like a charm. Only in case of 2013 version there is no way to detect E3BD1151... guid on the x64 machine with x64 excel. I tried to find in on both real and virtual machine without success. One guy also refers to the same problem here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bdcd8850-0b6a-4fd1-a0cb-647ff12c3088/finding-the-component-id-for-office-2013?forum=vsto